# How can I show the hover action for anchor tag on a phone before it junps to link?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

### things I'd like to make

I'm trying to show the hover action for anchor tag on a phone.
So that I wrote ontouchstart="" on parent element of that, and made child element to show the action by tapping screen.

But (as a matter of course,) it goes straight to links before showing the action.
Then, now I'm trying to make it
・showing hover action by First tap
・goes to link by Second tap .

these are the codes.

```html
    
        aタグ
        https://qiita.com/" id="sprite_dancer_a" class="sprite_dancer">

        divタグ(onclick属性)
        ">">https://www.google.com/'">
```

```css
.sprite_dancer {
  background-image: url("../img/test-image.png");
  width: 213px;
  height: 190px;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

// スプライトアニメーション

.sprite_dancer:hover{
  animation: sprite 1s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: -2130px 0; }
}
```

And here is the demo site below.
https://rsaeki0.parallel.jp/sprite-hover/

I checked this one on my phone(android,chrome), however it didn't work so well.
Sometimes it works absolutry I expected, but sometimes it doesn't keep hovering for first tap or it got to been never junps to link whatever I taped several times.

### things I'v tried

I worte jQuery that gives class by first tap, and junps to link by second tap.

```css
.animating {
  animation: sprite 1s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: -2130px 0; }
}
```

```js
// aタグをクリックした回数を記録する変数
let clickCount = 0;

// .sprite_dancerをクリックした際の処理
$(".sprite_dancer").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  clickCount++;
  if (clickCount === 1) {
    // アニメーションを開始する
    $(this).addClass("animating");
    setTimeout(function() {
      // アニメーションが終了したら、再度クリックした場合に備えて、
      // animatingクラスを除去する
      $(".sprite_dancer").removeClass("animating");
    }, 3000);
  } else if (clickCount === 2) {
    // リンク先へ遷移する
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
  }
});
```

I think this may works... but isn't this too forced?
Does someone know smarter and more efficient ways?

Or is it no longer a mistake to show the hover action wrote for the a tag on a smartphone, or to try to achieve that by writing ontouchstart itself?

Would you please advice me.
If there are some mistakes in English, I'd like to apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code for you on click event you use. That will be run on one click. You need to change your jQuery code.

```
// On Click Event
$(".sprite_dancer").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // add class on click
    $(this).addClass("animating");

    // Remove class after 3s.
    setTimeout(function () {
        
        $(".sprite_dancer").removeClass("animating");
    }, 3000);

    // Redirect to page after 4s.
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    }, 4000);

});
```